# Extracting data from excel using powerquery

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, m

I want to extract certain set of rows (let's say rows 10-30) from the same sheet (let's say sheet "income statement") present in multiple excel files to create a data dump (let's say "result") in an automated manner. Also, I want to shape the data in a particular way (basically pivoting and transposing on certain columns). I want to use powerquery (and probably M, if required) for this. Can someone help me with how to go about it, please?

Comment: Have you tried any methods / functions ? If yes, please put that too. That's how others can comment on your try.

Comment: You are going to need to watch some tutorials and look through related questions on here. Selecting specific rows from a named sheet is easy enough. Shaping your data all depends on your data and is too broad, at present, for here.